# Setting font size of UIBarButtonItem

Tags: swift, uibarbuttonitem

I am creating a `UIBarButtonItem` with the following code.

```
    let rightItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "➞", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "navigateToViewTwo")

    if let font = UIFont(name: "System", size: 25.0) {
        rightItem.setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: font], forState: UIControlState.Normal)}

    navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.rightBarButtonItem = rightItem
```

The button should display a right arrow, and it does.  The problem is that the font is not controlling the size of the button.  I get the following:

[image]

The only happens when using the System font.  I tried it with Helvetica, and I got the following:

[image]

The arrow is definitely larger, but it is also too high on the nav bar.  If I rotate the screen, it looks bad.

[image]

The arrow is too high, and looks out of place.  See how it looks, compared to the Item button on the left?  That one was dragged and dropped.

How can I adjust the arrow so that it is in the correct size, and in the correct place on the screen?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have to set title edge insets

### With CustomView

```
var btn = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as! UIButton
btn.frame = CGRectMake(10, 20, 50, 50)
btn.setTitle("➞", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
btn.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica" , size: 17)
btn.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(5, 0, 0, 0)
btn.addTarget(self, action: Selector("navigateToViewTwo"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
var right = UIBarButtonItem(customView: btn)
```

### With Normal as you have done

```
var rightItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "➞", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "navigateToViewTwo")
rightItem.setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 17.0)!], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
rightItem.setTitlePositionAdjustment(UIOffsetMake(0.0, 5.0), forBarMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)
```

Set both for comparison, just add it which looks batter :

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.rightBarButtonItems = [rightItem,right]
```

Results :

[image]

Hope it will help you.

Comment: This works great for rightBarButtonItems, but doesn't work at all for backBarButtonItems.  The backBarItem is not affected by the font setting.  It stays the same size.  Is there anything else that needs to be done to get this to work for all buttons?

Comment: @ScottKilbourn There is `leftBarButtonItems` if you want to add buttons to left side.

Comment: @ScottKilbourn If you want to set only one button then `rightBarButtonItem` or `leftBarButtonItem`

Answer (score 7):

```
UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor : UIColor(red:0.12, green:0.28, blue:0.40, alpha:1.0), NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont(name: "GalanoGrotesque-SemiBold", size: 18)!], for: .normal)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have encounter this problem before, and I decide to use a custom view to handle this as follow:

```
    var view = // create your custom view
    var btnMenu = UIBarButtonItem(customView: view)
```